# Create and Updating Multiple QLabel in PYQT4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel

How can I create a number of (say 56) labels within a widget in a loop?

Say I have a list called column:

```
column = ['a','b','c','d',.......'y','z']
```

What I did is:

```
class ApplicationWindow_1(QWidget):

  def __init__(self,parent = None):
      super(ApplicationWindow_1,self).__init__(parent)
      self.resize(400,900)

        for i in range(len(column)):
          column_name =  str(column[i]) + '_label_name'
          self.column_name = QLabel(column[i],self)
          self.column_name.resize(120,30)
          self.column_name.move(30,100+(i-1)*20)

          infor_name = str(column[i]) + '_label_infor'
          self.infor_name = QLabel(self)
          self.infor_name.resize(120,30)
          self.infor_name.move(230,100+(i-1)*20)
```

For each element in the list, there would be a corresponding blank QLabel. All blank Qlabes would be updated simultaneously by clicking the check button using the setText function.

brief view of the UI

[image]

I know this method is not right as I am not supposed to use the string as variable names, and I am having a problem updating infor_labels(the blank labels) since I can't actually call them.

Can anyone please kindly provide suggestions? Additional explanation or information will be given if the above description confuses.

Comment: Explain better, what do you mean by *All blank Qlabes would be updated simultaneously by clicking the check button using the setText function.*?, I assume that you are going to write something in the QLineEdit, and then press the button, do you want it to happen later ?, that is, if I enter the word "StackOverflow" in the QLineEdit, what should be shown in the QLabel?

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi, thanks for you reply.  Two columns of QLabels have been created, column_name(a,b,c,d) and infor_name(blank). By inputting information in the QLineEdit and clicking Check, the information would be updateed to infor_name labels. i didn't put the check button method code, but it would be like  u enter something, and it shows a:1 b:2 ......z :26.

Comment: @eyllanesc i will put it in a better way, for column_name, it's not a,b,c...z, it's name, address, phone number etc. and in QLineEdit you enter a person's name say Tim, the infor_name QLabels would show 'Tim','xxxx','123456'.

Comment: I'll understand you better, how do you point out that you have to fill in a different row, for example, how do you indicate that you should modify the infor_name corresponding to phone?

Comment: @eyllanesc For example,if it's only phone, i would create the QLabel like phone_infor_label = QLabel(self) and in the check method it would be self.phone_infor_label,setText(str(information i fetched from Mysql )), but since i have 20+ kinds of information to update, i am thinking if there is a better way to do it in loop.

Comment: I mean, you want the variable that reference infor_name corresponding to phone to be phone_infor_label, and if number is number_infor_label, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc YES! so for phone, i would need phone_name_label = 'Phone',self) and phone_infor_label = QLabel(self).

Comment: Try with my answer, if this helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @eyllanesc left office yesterday, will check today.  Don’t worry and thanks mate.

Comment: If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setattr()` to create variables dynamically using a string as shown below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class ApplicationWindow_1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(ApplicationWindow_1,self).__init__(parent)
        flay = QtGui.QFormLayout(self)

        texts = ["name", "address", "phone"]

        for text in texts:
            label_1 = QtGui.QLabel(text+": ")
            label_1.setFixedSize(120, 30)
            label_2 = QtGui.QLabel()
            label_2.setFixedSize(120, 30)
            flay.addRow(label_1, label_2)

            # An attribute of the class is created with setattr()
            setattr(self, "{}_infor_label".format(text), label_2)

        # use
        self.name_infor_label.setText("some name")
        self.address_infor_label.setText("some address")
        self.phone_infor_label.setText("some phone")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ApplicationWindow_1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If i have 20+ plus infor_labels, how can I update them in a loop in stead of setText one by one? I am getting error '''str' object has no attribute 'setText''  for my method.

Comment: @gu_lv  Use for loop: `for text in texts: getattr(self, text).setText("some_text")`

Comment: @eyllanese  should't it be for text in texts: getattr(self, "{}_infor_label".format(text)).setText("some_text")?